# Aggregating a vector of $1\times K$ into a vector $1\times J$, such as $J<K$

Tags: matrices, notation

I am stuck with a matrix algebra operation: how do I do (and mainly which notation to use) to aggregate the numbers of a vector $1\times K$ into a vector of $1\times J$, such as $J$ is of course lower than $K.$

Suppose we have vector $A_{1\times K}$ = $\{a_1, a_2, \dots, a_K\}$ and we whish to randomly aggregate those values $a_1$ to $a_K$ into a smaller vector $N_{1\times J} = \{b_1, b_2,\dots , b_J\}$, by summing up the aggregated values $a$ into their final values $b$.

Is there a way to do that only with matrix operations and especially, how to write it down with the proper notation?

Thanks!

EDIT: in response to the request in the comments, to clarify what I mean by aggregate, let's suppose vector A={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10} and we want to transform it into a vector B that has fewer numbers, let's say 3 numbers: B={B_1, B_2, B_3}.

I called it aggregation because the values of A would have to be summed. Let's say that to decide which will be summed to which, we have a third vector M={1,1,2,2,1,2,3,3,3,1} that serves as a 'mask'. I.e. it tells the 'categories' through which we are going to aggregate the values of A. As we end up having 3 values in B, so all values within M go from 1 to 3.
Corresponding A and M, then we find that category 1 includes A_1, A_2, A_5 and A_10, category 2 includes A_3, A_4 and A_6 and category 3 includes A_7, A_8 and A_9.

Therefore, in the end B={(A_1+A_2+A_5),(A_3+A_4+A_6),(A_7+A_8+A_9)}, or B={18,13,24}.
Forget about what I called "randomly" in the original question, it can be seem here as just generating M randomly, but does not matter for the main question.

Comment: Randomly? And what do you mean "aggregate"? If you mean "sum" then yes, linear operations on the coefficients can be expressed as a matrix. If you mean something else... well, please clarify.

Comment: Ready. I've edited the original question with plenty more details. Thanks for calling my attention for the previous lack of info. If you  (or anyone reading) need more details or some specific clarification, I am more than glad to try explaining what I need.

Answer (score 0):

We will use *column vectors*. That is, for your example, I will write the vector $A$ as

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3 \\ 4 \\ 5 \\ 6 \\ 7 \\ 8 \\ 9 \\ 10 \end{bmatrix} $$

If you are given exactly a mask $M$ with the same length as $A$, you can generate a masking matrix, which I will call $\mathfrak{M}$, by the following procedure:

1. If the dimension of $A$ is $K$, and if the dimension of $B$ is $J$, the matrix $\mathfrak{M}$ is a $J\times K$ matrix. So in your example $K = 10$ and $J = 3$ so $\mathfrak{M}$ has 3 rows and 10 columns.
2. Each individual column of $\mathfrak{M}$ is related to $M$ as follows: the $k$th column of $\mathfrak{M}$ can be computed from the $k$th entry of $M$. If the $k$th entry of $M$ is $j$, the $k$th column of $\mathfrak{M}$ is the column vector with all zeros except for the $j$th entry, where it takes the value 1. Let me show it with the example you gave: you have $M = (1,1,2,2,1,2,3,3,3,1)$ so we make
   $$ \mathfrak{M} = \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
   0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0
   \end{bmatrix} $$
3. Now if you multiply $\mathfrak{M} \times A$ using standard matrix multiplication, you will receive exactly the $B$ that you want.